# Forcing \bibname to all capitals

Tags: bibliographies, capitalization

I need to enforce a style guideline which requires that all chapter and chapter-level equivalents have their headers and table of contents entries in all capital letters.  I've managed this for most everything at this point, but am running into problems with the bibliography.  I know that I can preset the bibliography name to be all caps by redefining `\bibname` (the class file is based on a the `report` class).  However, I need to support users who might redefine the `\bibname` themselves (or by use of something like `babel`) so I'd like to find a programatic way to force the `\bibname`, whatever it is, to be in all caps.  Unfortunately, my attempts at this far have failed.

What I've tried is to replace the `\bibliography` command with a replacement which first recases `\bibname`, adds the ToC entry, and then calls the old `\bibliography` command, as can be seen in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref} %must be supported, but not required

\makeatletter

\providecommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{%
    #1%
}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
        \typeout{*** \@chapapp\space\thechapter\space ****}%
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak[3]}%
        \def\@LastLevel{0}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.}\space\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
    \else
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak[3]}%
        \def\@LastLevel{0}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
}


\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \vspace*{0\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \centering\normalfont\Large
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \bfseries \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\ \thechapter
            \vskip -3pt
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \bfseries\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}\par\nobreak
        \vskip 15\p@
    }%
}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \vspace*{0\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \centering\normalfont\Large
        \interlinepenalty\@M
%        \bfseries \texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}\par\nobreak
        \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 15\p@
    }%
}

%% Unnumbered bibliography
\let\oldbibliography\bibliography
\renewcommand\bibliography{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}{\bibname}}%
  \oldbibliography
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page Style Definitions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\ps@bottom}{%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth % <-- This is the problematic line
    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{}%
    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\@oddfoot}
}

\pagestyle{bottom}

\makeatother

%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\cite{book-full}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong and how I might fix it?

Note: The MWE is exapanded to include the existing code which enforces capitaliation for regular chapters and a slightly simplified version of the custom page style, which appears to raise conflicts with attempted solutions so far.

Edit: Some additional experimentation on my part has narrowed down the conflicting code even further.  I've marked the line that appears to cause the solution given by @phelype-oleinik to fail.  That line, unfortunately, is part of the code I inherited when I took over maintenance of this class file, so I don't know how necessary it is.  If you think that removing it is the answer to solving this conflict, please indicate why it may not be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `\@makeschapterhead` the same you did to `\@makechapterhead` and add the `\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}` thing:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref} %must be supported, but not required

\makeatletter

\providecommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{%
    #1%
}


\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
             {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \refstepcounter{chapter}%
        \typeout{*** \@chapapp\space\thechapter\space ****}%
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak[3]}%
        \def\@LastLevel{0}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.}\space\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
    \else
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\pagebreak[3]}%
        \def\@LastLevel{0}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
}


\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \vspace*{0\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \centering\normalfont\Large
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
            \bfseries \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\ \thechapter
            \vskip -3pt
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \bfseries\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}\par\nobreak
        \vskip 15\p@
    }%
}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \vspace*{0\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \centering\normalfont\Large
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \bfseries \texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#1}\par\nobreak
        \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 15\p@
    }%
}

%% Unnumbered bibliography
\let\oldbibliography\bibliography
\renewcommand\bibliography{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{\bibname}}{\bibname}}%
  \oldbibliography
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page Style Definitions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\ps@bottom}{%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth % <-- This is the problematic line
    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{}%
    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\@oddfoot}
}

\pagestyle{bottom}

\makeatother

%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\cite{book-full}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

You will still need to manually issue an `\addcontentsline` for the bibliography, since it's an unnumbered chapter (I commented an option to make it numbered, if you want).

Also, due to an oddity of LaTeX's standard classes (kept for compatibility with LaTeX 2.09. See [`classes.dtx`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/base/classes.dtx) around line 3739 or [`classes.pdf`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/classes.pdf) section 8.1.1 -- Table of Contents). Different from the `\listoffigures` and such, which contain:

```
\chapter*{\listfigurename}%
 \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
```

the `\tableofcontents` macro contains:

```
\chapter*{\contentsname
 \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
         {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
```

Note the `\@mkboth` instruction *inside* the `\chapter*` command in the second case. This will pass `\@mkboth` (which is `\let` to `\markboth`) to `\MakeUppercase` which whill, essentially, do `\MakeUppercase{\markboth{sur}{prise!}}`. I had the *exact* same problem when writing [this class](https://gitlab.com/PhelypeOleinik/EoTeX) and the solution I found was to make `\tableofcontents` have a similar code to `\listoffigures`:

```
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname}%
     \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
             {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

and I saw no difference between this one and the other (modulo that it didn't compile previously :P). And as it says in the documentation, it's for compatibility...

Comment: Works in the MWE, but I seem to be running into some problems in the actual use.  There seems to be a conflict when `hyperref` is loaded, and I need to support (though not require) that package.

Comment: @rpspringuel Hmm... before delving into `hyperref` (not pleasant, I assure you), I must ask: how are you uppercasing the other chapter headings? Perhaps the solution will be easier, `hyperref` compatible, and more robust than redefining `\bibname`. Can you please expand you MWE so I can see how you did it for other chapters?

Comment: Done.  See the modified MWE above.

Comment: @rpspringuel Done. It's really much easier this way :)

Comment: This MWE compiles just fine, but there's some complicating factor in the actual class file as when I try to apply it I get an error: Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.  I'm not sure what the complicating factor is yet, but I'm working on isolating it.  Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: @rpspringuel Strange... Have you tried deleting temporary files?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Still get the same error.

Comment: @rpspringuel I have no Idea then... Try to reduce the code as much as you can then post it here.

Comment: Found the problem.  It appears to be in the custom page style that's in effect.  I've added that to the MWE (in a slightly simplified version, to avoid code related to other options in the class style).

Comment: @rpspringuel Sorry to take so long. I'm a bit busy lately. I updated my answer to get it working.

Comment: That explains things.  I've got things working now but actually I think I'm going to remove the `\@mkboth` stuff altogether.  The class I'm working on never has anything in the header except possibly for the page number, so it's just easier to  avoid the trouble completely.