# What is the functional difference between these two page styles?

Tags: header-footer

I maintain a class file which I inherited and which contained the following page style in the inherited code:

```
\newcommand{\ps@bottom}{%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{}%
    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\hfil\thepage\hfil}
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\@oddfoot}
}
```

Recently I've been making [some modifications to the class file which have run into a conflict with the first line in this page style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456005/forcing-bibname-to-all-capitals).  When I removed that line, my modifications worked and the page style seems, at first glance to still be working fine too.  Before I make such a change permanent though, I'd like to understand the implications of removing that line.  Put another way, what's the difference in the expected behavior of the above page style and this one:

```
\newcommand{\ps@bottom}{%
    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{}%
    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\hfil\thepage\hfil}
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\@oddfoot}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that one defines `\@mkboth` and the other does not. Whether that makes any functional difference depends on whether `\@mkboth` is called anywhere and that depends on details you have not shown.

`\@mkboth` is not called by any command in the latex format but is used by the standard classes.

For example `article` class defines

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

so the table of contents sets marks or not depending on whether `\@mkboth` is `\markboth` or `\@gobbletwo`

The `headings` page style sets it to `\markboth` the `empty` page style sets it to `\@gobbletwo` for example.

Comment: So it’s a simple matter of checking how `\@mkboth` is used elsewhere in the class file and the `report` class (from which this class file is derived).  Excuse me while I go bang my head against the desk before doing some `grep`ing.